# Power Query | Loop with delay

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm new to PQ and trying to do following:

1. Get updates from server
2. Transform it.
3. Post data back.

While code works just fine i'd like it to be performed each N minutes until application closure.
Also LastMessageId variable should be revaluated after each call of GetUpdates() and i need to somehow call GetUpdates() again with it.

I've tried Function.InvokeAfter but didn't get how to run it more than once.
Recursion blow stack out ofc.

The only solution i see is to use List.Generate but struggle to understand how it can be used with delay.

```
let
    //Get list of records
    GetUpdates = (optional offset as number) as list => 1,
    Updates = GetUpdates(),
    // Store last update_id
    LastMessageId = List.Last(Updates)[update_id],
    // Prepare and response
    Process = (item as record) as record =>
    // Map Process function to each item in the list of records
    Map = List.Transform(Updates, each Process(_))
in
    Map
```

Comment: See `Value.WaitFor()` for a loop with a delay, like async  polling https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/helperfunctions#valuewaitfor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerBI does not support continuous automatic re-loading of data in the desktop.

Online, you can enforce a refresh as fast as 15 minutes using direct query<sup>1</sup>

Alternative methods:

- You could do this in Excel and use VBA to re-execute the query on a schedule
- Streaming data in PowerBI<sup>2</sup>
- Streaming data with Flow and PowerBI<sup>3</sup>

1: [Supported DirectQuery Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-data-sources)

2: [Realtime Streaming in PowerBI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-real-time-streaming)

3: [Streaming data with Flow](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/push-rows-to-a-power-bi-streaming-dataset-without-writing-any-code-using-microsoft-flow/)

4: Don't forget to enable historic logging!